# Laplace transform of $\csc(x)$

Tags: laplace-transform

In exponential form, $\csc(x)$ is
$$\csc(x)=\frac1{\sin(x)}=\frac{2i}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}$$
How do I prove whether or not the Laplace transform for $\csc(x)$ exists?

Comment: It has inifnitely many poles so $\int_0^\infty \frac{2i}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}e^{-sx}dx$ diverges. But you can modify it in a lot of ways, for example the distributional derivative of $1_{x > 0}\log|e^{ix}-e^{-ix}|$.

Comment: $\mathcal{L}_t[\csc (t)](s)=\frac{1}{2} \left(-\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i s}{2}\right)-\psi
   \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i s}{2}\right)\right)$ where $\psi$ is digamma function.